What's the point of threads if ruby has GIL and can only execute one thread at time?
I read this about ruby:
"If one of these threads wants to execute some Ruby code, it will have to acquire this lock. One, and only one, thread can hold the lock at any given time. While one thread holds the lock, other threads need to wait for their turn to acquire the lock."
Since other threads have to wait to acquire the lock, having multiple threads gives an illusion of parallel execution when it fact it is just serial in nature.
I'm confused then, what's the point of having threads when it is  just behaving in a single threaded manner?

I/O — if one thread is waiting another thread can compute. For example a server handling multiple clients as shown in TCPServer

You could also take a look at the Ractor class. Ractors operate on a so called "RIL" rather than "GIL" (GVL) so multiple Ractors can run multiple threads in parallel. There are some trade offs regarding what is shareable though so it depends on what you are trying to do.

That's a bit of a jump. The main assumption you are making is that the CPU is in use for the entire time a process is running. But this is not actually true for most processes.
The most egregious example is the sleep function. The time to complete this is about 20 seconds:
sleep(10)
sleep(10)

But if we put this in threads, the time to complete is about 10 seconds.
threads = []
threads << Thread.new { sleep(10) }
threads << Thread.new { sleep(10) }

threads.each(&:join)

Most processes have execution time where they don't use the CPU, so the Thread class is very helpful for a concurrent model. Although, of course, there are gotchas.

Fibers are also a fantastic option when you want to control the concurrency


What's the point of threads if ruby has GIL and can only execute one thread at time?

This information is wrong. Ruby does not have a GIL.
Ruby is a programming language. A programming language is an abstract concept, it is a set of mathematical rules and restrictions. An "interpreter lock" is not the property of a programming language like Ruby. It is a property of a specific (set of) version(s) of a specific implementation of a programming language.
Some programming languages have a single, unified, document where you can look up the definition of the programming language. Unfortunately, Ruby does not have that. There are several resources, the sum of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.
Some of these resources are:

The ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby specification – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV and MacRuby only implement Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower and JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, and IronRuby (at the time) only implemented a subset of Ruby 1.8, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify Strings very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors or Pattern Matching.
The Ruby Spec Suite aka ruby/spec – Note that the ruby/spec is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
The Ruby Programming Language by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
Programming Ruby by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as the standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
The Ruby Issue Tracking System, specifically, the Feature sub-tracker – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
The Meeting Logs of the Ruby Developer Meetings. (Same problem: Ruby and YARV get intermingled.)
New features are often discussed on the mailing lists, in particular the ruby-core (English) and ruby-dev (Japanese) mailing lists. (Same problem again.)
The Ruby documentation – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the Ruby Change Request (RCR) and Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they actually do. Please note the plural: you have to look at multiple, ideally all, implementations to figure out what the consensus is. Only looking at one implementation cannot possibly tell you whether what you are looking at is an implementation quirk of this particular implementation or is a universally agreed-upon behavior of the Ruby Language.

You will find that none of those resources specify a GIL.
The GIL is a property of the implementation, not the programming language. For example, YARV does have a GIL (called the Giant VM Lock (GVL)), but JRuby, TruffleRuby, and many other Ruby implementations do not.

Since other threads have to wait to acquire the lock, having multiple threads gives an illusion of parallel execution when it fact it is just serial in nature.

That is how threads have always worked in all programming languages and operating systems, especially in the mainstream market. Having more than one CPU in a computer is an extremely recent development for consumers. Not too long ago, only supercomputers and very expensive, super high-performance workstations and servers even had multiple CPUs.
For example, the first Apple computer with multiple CPUs was only introduced in 1996. It was the Power Macintosh 9500/180MP. But MacOS itself was not capable of running on multiple CPUs, so this was not an SMP system, it was an AMP system, where only specially-written software could take control of the second CPU. So, even in the dual-CPU version, threads were still not running in parallel.
The first computer I personally saw that was even capable of running with more than one CPU was an Opteron server my father bought for his business in 2004. It had a dual-socket motherboard. However, for cost reasons, we decided to first only install a single first-generation Opteron 140 in it, i.e., the single-CPU version that wasn't even capable of SMP. We planned to sell the 140 at a later date and replace it with two second-generation 242s or 244s, but in the end, we never did.
The first computer I personally owned with multiple CPUs, was a 2011 MacBook Pro with 2 cores, which I used until 2019.

I'm confused then, what's the point of having threads when it is just behaving in a single threaded manner?

First off, to repeat, you, or more precisely, the author of the statement you quoted, are confusing a limitation of YARV with a limitation of Ruby. Those are not the same thing. There are plenty of Ruby implementations other than YARV, such as TruffleRuby or JRuby, and many more.
But, even if you only consider YARV, you are still missing two important bits of the statement you quoted [bold italic emphasis mine]:

If one of these threads wants to execute some Ruby code, it will have to acquire this lock. One, and only one, thread can hold the lock at any given time. While one thread holds the lock, other threads need to wait for their turn to acquire the lock.

First off, you only need to acquire the lock in order to execute Ruby code. But a thread can do plenty of things other than "executing Ruby code". In particular, it can be waiting for something. For example, a server may be waiting for a client to connect, a GUI thread may be waiting for a user action (a mouse click, etc.), a processing thread may be waiting for data to come in, a thread reading from a file may be waiting for the I/O to happen, and so on.
And secondly, this only applies to Ruby code. In YARV, practically the entire core library and some parts of the standard library, are not written in Ruby. The parts that are not written in Ruby have direct access to the GVL and can drop it if they don't need it, which means that another thread can acquire it and run in parallel. In particular, many I/O methods in YARV release the GVL and only re-acquire it, once the I/O has finished.
So, while you can have only one thread executing Ruby code, you can have plenty of other threads executing non-Ruby code or waiting.
If you want to know more about how YARV schedules Ruby threads, you can read Feature #19842 Introduce M:N threads. While this feature is about Ractors, not threads, it also discusses how threads are scheduled.

IIRC, I've seen you posting that list (or a similar one) before a few times. Why not turn the list of resources as a reference into a separate (community wiki) question / answer. Maybe as general as "What is Ruby?", covering authoritative sources regarding the language as well as its implementations.
